# Yaw, Pitch and Roll composition

Tags: matrices, rotations

I'm trying to understand composition of rotations using eulers angles and rotation matrices.
I am facing a counterintuitive situation performing two rotations about different angles.
My setting is the following:

- first rotation of an angle $\psi$ about the Z body-axis (yaw)
- second rotation of an angle $\theta$ about the Y body-axis (pitch)
- third rotation of an angle $\varphi$ about the X body-axis (roll)

Denoting with

$$R_X=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\
0&\cos(\varphi)&-\sin(\varphi)\\
0&\sin(\varphi)&\cos(\varphi)\end{bmatrix}$$
$$R_Y=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&0&\sin(\theta)\\
0&1&0\\
-\sin(\theta)&0&\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$$
$$R_Z=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\psi)&-\sin(\psi)&0\\
\sin(\psi)&\cos(\psi)&0\\
0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

the rotation matrices relative to elementary rotation about the three body axis, I obtain that a general rotation of eulers angles $(yaw,pitch,roll)=(\psi,\theta,\varphi)$ is given by:

$$R=R_X\cdot R_Y\cdot R_Z$$

Suppose now that I would like to perform this 2 consecutive rotations:

1. Rotation of $(yaw,pitch,roll)=(0,\frac{\pi}{4},0)$
2. Rotation of $(yaw,pitch,roll)=(\frac{\pi}{2},0,0)$

The matrices relative to these two rotations are the following:

$$R_1=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&0&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
0&1&0\\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&0&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$R_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\
0&0&-1\\
0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

and composing them I obtain the total rotation matrix

$$R=R_2\cdot R_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0&-1&0\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&0&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&0&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

If I want to recover the euler angles sequence relative to $R$ I apply these equations:

$$\theta=\arcsin(R_{13})\\
\psi=-\arctan2\left(\frac{R_{12}}{\cos(\theta)},\frac{R_{11}}{\cos(\theta)}\right)\\
\varphi=-\arctan2\left(\frac{R_{23}}{\cos(\theta)},\frac{R_{33}}{\cos(\theta)}\right)$$

obtaining $(yaw,pitch,roll)=(\frac{\pi}{2},0,-\frac{\pi}{4})$.

However applying this sequence of rotation I do not recover the initial frame (sequence of rotations 1-2) unless the rotations 1-2 are performed on different axis respect the body ones.

Probably I miss something and I'm making confusion with these concepts.
Please, could you help me to understand where I miss?

Comment: A side comment : I have seen that you haven't checked any answer to your your last 15 questions (some of them are 1 year old). This is definitely not a good practise on this site. Moreover, it takes such a few time to do it... Consider a max. 2-4 weeks delay for checking answers (thorough answers of course).

Comment: If you want to recover Euler angles, are you aware that you have to use twice a $R_Z$ type matrix (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie you're right. I checked all my previous questions and I have choosen an answer for them. For the second comment I cannot understand it. For yaw,pitch and roll I mean rotations about three different axis (maybe I call them Euler's angles improperly).

Comment: Honestly, I am not accustomed to YPR. But I have seen that indeed, you are using $R_Z$ twice ; thus it is the same as Euler's angles ; see as well https://math.stackexchange.com/q/147028.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem you are having is that if you multiply the matrices in the order $R_X\cdot R_Y\cdot R_Z$, then you are rotating first around the *global* $Z$ axis, then the *global* $Y$ axis, then the *global* $X$ axis.

To get the rotations applied to the local (body) axes instead, you simply have to reverse the order of multiplication.

This might seem like magic, so I'll give a short explanation. After applying the $Z$-axis rotation, the body reference frame is not the same as the global reference frame: It has been rotated by $R_Z$. So at this point, if $A$ is a matrix denoting any transformation according to the body frame, then in the global frame that same transformation has the matrix representation
$$
R_Z\cdot A\cdot R_Z^{-1}
$$
(This will take a vector expressed in the global basis, then $R_Z^{-1}$ is the same vector expressed in the body basis. We apply $A$, then translate back to the global basis with $R_Z$.)

So first applying $R_Z$, then after that applying $R_Y$ in the new local frame has matrix representation
$$
\left(R_Z\cdot R_Y\cdot R_Z^{-1}\right)\cdot R_Z = R_Z\cdot R_Y
$$
If you want to apply a rotation about the body $X$-axis after this again, then similarily, the global matrix representation of this transformation is
$$
(R_Z\cdot R_Y)\cdot R_X\cdot (R_Z\cdot R_Y)^{-1}
$$
and if we apply this after our initial rotation of $R_Z\cdot R_Y$, then the result becomes
$$
R_Z\cdot R_Y\cdot R_X
$$

Comment: Thank you. You were very clear. So, if I would like to apply two consecutive rotations, say $R_1,R_2$, I need to premultiply body vectors by $R_1\cdot R_2\cdot R_1^{-1}$ isn't it? Is there a simpler (and computational cheaper) way?